# spring xd on openstack

Tags: spring-xd

Can Spring XD run on top of OpenStack which is a Iaas/Paas.
As Hadoop service can be encapsulated or integrated on Openstack, Supposing Spring XD has interface with OpenStack to talk to hadoop framework, is it something which is already supported?

Answer (score 0):

Openstack is used to setup virtual linux machines, storage and network. And you can run the Spring XD processes (xd-worker, xd-master) on these linux machines. So, yes you can run Spring XD on openstack.

You could also run Spring XD on top of Yarn running on Openstack. See the Spring XD guide for this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#running-on-YARN . This way you can share the computing resources between Spring XD and Hadoop jobs.

Spring XD can interoperate with Hadoop (to be precise: with HDFS) through its HDFS-Sinks and HDFS-Sources.